# Google Apps Script Hanging Up (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The following Javascript is hanging up. I've been teaching myself Apps Script to sort data on a sheet. My web developer friend and I have been clueless for the last 2 hours as to why this particular script stalls. It just says Running Script forever....

What is happening is that I have a section of a spreadsheet designated as a calendar area which already has a dynamic calendar printed onto it by one of my other functions. For testing purposes I isolated this function and gave it a dummy array, but the function should loop through the calendar, locate the COORDs of the 'date' i.e. 1,2,3,4th and return the coordinates of an empty cell below that date (the place where i will put data into the calendar).

```
function printCalendarValues(array){ 
  var array = [0,143,534,342,54,1,41,1];
  var Calendar_Display_range = recruiter_sheet.getRange('B8:H19');
  var Calendar_Display_values = Calendar_Display_range.getValues();     
  function getCellBelow(day, rangeArray){
    for(i=0; i<rangeArray.length; i++){
      for(j=0;j<rangeArray[i].length; j++){
        if(rangeArray[i][j]==day){
          var res = [i+9,j+2];
          return res;
        };        
      };
    }
  };  
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){ //< ---- THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS
    // If I take the code in this for loop out of it and run it
    // only once then it runs as expected. It breaks when I put it in
    // this for loop. You can see I only loop twice right now. I 
    // did that for testing, but i've tried twice, or array.length 
    // anything other than running it once breaks it.
    var cellBelow = getCellBelow(i+1, Calendar_Display_values);  
    recruiter_sheet.getRange(cellBelow[0],cellBelow[1]).setValue(array[i]);
  }; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either define the variable `i` at the top of your function.

```
function printCalendarValues(array){
  var i;//Define i - its' value will be undefined
```

Or you need to add the `var` keyword inside the `for` parameters.  `for (var i = 0, etc`  Right now, the variable `i` is a global.  The value of `i` is in the "global scope."  *Any* function that you run will have access to `i` as it is right now.

When your second `for` loop calls the `getCellBelow` function, both the `for` loop and the function `getCellBelow` are sharing the variable `i`.  So, `i` gets set to  1, then function `getCellBelow` gets called.  Then `i` gets set back to zero.  So your `for` loop will go on forever.  It never gets to 1.  It is constantly being set back to zero by the `getCellBelow` function.

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){ //i gets set to zero and then incremented to 1
  var cellBelow = getCellBelow(i+1, Calendar_Display_values);//function called
```

Then in function getCellBelow;

```
for(i=0; i<rangeArray.length; i++){//i is set to zero and until the array lengh
```

So, `i` could easily now be greater than one.  And your loop `for(i=0;i<2;i++){` will stop.

You can see this by adding `Logger.log('i: ' + i)` statements, and then viewing the Log.  In View menu, choose Logs after running the code.

You should define `i` inside of the function `function getCellBelow(day, rangeArray){`

Should be:

```
function getCellBelow(day, rangeArray){
  var i;
```

So, the usage of `i` inside that function will be confined to the function and not affect any other value of `i` outside of that function.